# Add note based on value of another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For all I researched, I know there is not an integrated funcion that can do this, but I know it can be done with scripts. I want a script to create note in one specific cell based on another specific cell value.
example in the sheet I'll share
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7ictcN_tEQyZXFljAVFm1VqZzafIezF1xR5AYW5pVc/edit?usp=sharing
I want the note on D12 to reflect any changes in the value of A8 for example.

Best case would be, if I could use this script as a function calling whatever cell I wanted.
I saw some examples using onEdit as trigger but I don't know if that would work because the cell in question wouldnt even be touched.
I also saw some exemples using get range to target the cells but then I would have to make a  new script for each iteration.

Comment: you can us onEdit trigger if changes are due to user edit.  Otherwise there is no trigger to accomplish that other that using time based triggers and polling for changes

Comment: they aren't. they are cells that contain a formula, won't be directly edited

Answer (score 0):

Recording User Edits in A8 in the Notes of D12

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 8) {
    sh.getRange(12,4).setNote(sh.getRange(12,4).getNote() + '\n' + e.value);
  }
}
```